# C++ : Handling input

Tags: c++

```
char d;
do
{
    cout<<"1.Easy\n";
    cout<<"2.Medium\n";
    cout<<"3.Hard\n";
    cout<<"Choose your difficulty:";
    cin>>d;
    if (d=='1')
    {
        //function call
        break;
    }
    else
    if (d=='2')
    {
        //function call
        break;
    }
    else
    if (d=='3')
    {
        //function call
        break;
    }
    else
        cout<<"Invalid Input!\n";
}while (d=='1' || d=='2' || d=='3') ;
```

The above code runs till `d` has a value 1 , 2 or 3.

But when I enter a letter, such as `"e"`, it doesn't show the `"invalid input"` message. Instead, the loop is exited and a blank screen is shown. Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Um if this is supposed to run *until* `d` is 1,2, or 3, shouldn't that while condition be wrapped up in a *not* operator ? `while (!(d=='1' || d=='2' || d=='3'))` ?

Comment: All other issues aside, the program might be exiting before standard output can flush. I tested this in MSVC 2013 and got the expected output.

Comment: @anthony-arnold which *will* flush on program exit unless the process is hard-terminated (killed).

Comment: Other than the conditional in the `while()`, the posted code looks OK to me.

Comment: @WhozCraig True, although the OP might be running this in an unusual environment. Maybe a console is closing?

Comment: @anthony-arnold COmpiler says thread stopped , access violation

Comment: Well, that'll certainly reopen the no flush theory. Looks like you have another question you need to ask.

Comment: Take out the uncompilable (for us) `a.setdifficulty` junk and see if it still blows up. And next time, post code that *compiles* (for us) and *demonstrates the problem*. We have no idea what `a` is, where it came from, what `setdifficulty` does, etc.

Comment: @WhozCraig sorry , will edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to check the value of `d` in the `while` condition if you have the `break` in each valid case:

```
while (true) {
        cout << "1.Easy\n";
        cout << "2.Medium\n";
        cout << "3.Hard\n";
        cout << "Choose your difficulty:";
        cin >> d; 
        if (d == '1') {
                a.setdifficulty("Easy");
                break;  
        }       
        else if (d == '2') {
                a.setdifficulty("Medium");
                break;  
        }       
        else if (d == '3') {
                a.setdifficulty("Hard");
                break;  
        }       
        else    
                cout << "Invalid Input!\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing the loop only IF d == '1', '2', or '3'. You need to check to make sure that it is not one of these characters. This can be done by utilizing the following adjustment to the code:

```
char d;
do
{
..........
}while ( ! (d=='1' || d=='2' || d=='3') ) ;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Right logic, but rendered pointless by the OP's break statements.

Comment: @user4581301 Quite true, but I find it generally is better to show someone how to fix their logic; as apposed to applying a patch to the problem and using while(true) with break statements. (Don't get me wrong, I love break statements, and use them all the time. However in this case, they aren't necessary. Proper logic is the more elegant solution. )

Comment: You know what? I agree with you on that one. Personally I'd replace the ifs with a switch and that'll make a right mess of loop-busting break statements.

Comment: @user4581301 Switches would have been far superior in this case in my opinion as well. However, the OP was only asking for the ending logic to be fixed, not the assessment logic.

Answer (score 1):

The loop executes while the value of d is either '1' or '2' or '3'. To execute the loop untill it takes a valid input just change the condition like this code

```
char d;
do
{
    cout<<"1.Easy\n";
    cout<<"2.Medium\n";
    cout<<"3.Hard\n";
    cout<<"Choose your difficulty:";
    cin>>d;
    if (d=='1')
    {
        a.setdifficulty("Easy");
        break;
    }
    else
    if (d=='2')
    {
        a.setdifficulty("Medium");
        break;
    }
    else
    if (d=='3')
    {
        a.setdifficulty("Hard");
        break;
    }
    else
        cout<<"Invalid Input!\n";
}while (d!='1' && d!='2' && d!='3') ;
```

Comment: If you're going to rewrite the while-condition, maybe write one that works as described: `while (d != '1' && d != '2' && d != '3');` is one such possibility.

Comment: The while condition will always be true. This works due to the `break` statements. Just replace the condition with `true`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you want......your code will always execute one time.....for inputs 1,2,3 you break out of look and in case of invalid out put your conditions does not match in while loop.....

```
do
{
    cout<<"1.Easy\n";
    cout<<"2.Medium\n";
    cout<<"3.Hard\n";
    cout<<"Choose your difficulty:";
    cin>>d;
    if (d=='1')
    {
        cout<<"Easy";
        break;
    }
    else
        if (d=='2')
        {
            cout<<"DIFF";
            break;
        }
        else
            if (d=='3')
            {
                cout<<"Hard";
                break;
            }
            else
                cout<<"Invalid Input!\n";
}while (d!='1' || d!='2' || d!='3') ;
```